# How to add an onclick function to an element in opener window?

Tags: javascript, onclick, window.opener

I work on a webpage that opens a popup with a picture selector. The pictures added to a selection list are immediately cloned as thumbnails to opener window - that part works fine.

Problem occurs when I try to make these thumbnails clickable, like this:

```
opener.document.getElementById("someid").onclick = function(){ alert("bam!"); }
```

So far I only managed to have this working when a popup window is still opened (instead of plain alert(...) I used `opener.window.alert("bam!")`). However, when I close popup window, clicking the thumbnails results in errors.

Anyone out there who had similar problem and got it working? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

OK, I found not the prettiest solution, but so far it works. I had to declare extra function in opener window:

```
function addbam(id){
    document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){ alert("bam!"); }
}
```

And in a popup window:

```
opener.addbam("someid");
```

If this solution survives multi-browser test, it will stay with me, however I'm pretty sure it should be possible to remove "wrong" scope from such onclick declarations in much straightforward manner.

Thanks guys, your suggestions got me thinking more productive way.

Comment: the `opener` property gives you the `window` object of the parent window - `getElementById` is a property of `document` not `window`. Try `window.opener.document.getElementById...` instead. That being said, `opener.window` is redundant.

Comment: You are right. The actual code uses opener.document.getElementById and opener.window.alert. Sorry for the lack of accuracy. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery:

```
$("#someid").on('click', function () {  
    alert("bam");
});
```

or **without** jquery:
---------EDIT----------

```
//you put your element in a variablle
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

/*you add an event listenner to your variable, when click is triggered, it runs what's inside the brackets*/
div.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    alert("BAM!");
});
```

here's an example made just for you :)

http://jsfiddle.net/YDFLV/50/

Comment: the `on()` function does not exist on a DOM element.

Comment: Ok jbabey, thats the final version finally :) and it works.. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I hope this will work in opener-child window relations, since I'm close to abandoning the concept altogether and putting the thumbnails in <a> elements...

Comment: update: That's interesting. This time firebug reported 'attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope'. If the child window is still opened, 'bams' are shown as expected (either in child window with standalone 'alert', or in opener window when 'opener.window.alert' is used). How to convince the browser that I want to use opener's function, and not the one from child window?